# What is the difference between a variable and an automatic read-write property?

Tags: apex, apex-variable, properties

Accordingly to the [Apex Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_properties.htm),

> An Apex property is similar to a variable; however, you can do additional things in your code to a property value before it is accessed or returned.

However, properties do not require additional code in their get or set accessor code blocks. I don't understand if exist a difference between a variable and an automatic read-write property regardless of the access and definition modifiers used.

I would really appreciate a clarification on this topic and maybe some references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason why there is a distinction is because of Visualforce. You **cannot** access a *variable* in Visualforce, but you **can** access a *property*.

To illustrate this at the most basic level, consider this code:

```
public class myController {
  public String helloWorld = 'Hello, world!';
}
```

---

```
<apex:page controller="myController">
  <!-- following line causes a compile error -->
  {!helloWorld}
</apex:page>
```

This code will fail to compile because `helloWorld` is a variable, not a property. To fix this, we need to change it to a property:

```
public class myController {
  public String helloWorld { get; set; }
  public myController() {
    helloWorld = 'Hello, world!';
  }
}
```

So, even though the automatic read-write property may seem superfluous in code, it is actually required in certain contexts. Note that this is not the only way you can expose a variable to Visualforce, but those are outside the scope of the question and this answer.

If a variable will never be exposed directly to Visualforce, then there is no other reason why you'd want to turn it in to a read-write property, since it would just be a waste of code.

Of course, in library code, it might be useful to have read-only or write-only properties, or do constraint checks, etc, so there's plenty of reasons why you might use any of the various permutations of property getters and setters.